# Can EF 4.1+ generate optional parameters on Function Imports?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have a function import to a SQL Proc which has several optional SQL parameters.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.SomeProc ( @mandatoryField INT, 
                           @optionalField1 INT = NULL, 
                           @optionalField2 DATETIME = NULL ... )
```

However, after the import, on the generated method on my DbContext, EF creates the signature as follows:

```
    public virtual ObjectResult<SomeType> SomeProc(int mandatoryField, 
                                                   Nullable<int> optionalField1, 
                                                   Nullable<DateTime> optionalField2, ...)
```

Which means when I call the proc I need to provide explicit nulls, resulting in cumbersome code:

```
context.SomeProc(valueOfMandatoryField, null, null, ...)
```

Is there a way to get EF to use C# optional parameters in the function import mapping (even if it means hacking SSDL / CSDL directly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Parameter" element in SSDL and CSDL has no "DefaultValue" attribute, when creating "FunctionImport". I think, the easiest way to do what you want is to write custom extension method for generated context class:

```
public static class MyContext_Extensions
{
    public static ObjectResult<Nullable<global::System.Int32>> SomeProc(this MyContext context,
        Nullable<global::System.Int32> mandatoryField, 
        Nullable<global::System.Int32> optionalField1 = null, 
        Nullable<global::System.DateTime> optionalField2 = null)
    {
        return context.SomeProc(mandatoryField, optionalField1, optionalField2);
    }
}
```

...or add overload (context class is partial) without last parameter to exclude ambiguity:

```
public partial class MyContext
{
    public ObjectResult<Nullable<global::System.Int32>> SomeProc(
        Nullable<global::System.Int32> mandatoryField,
        Nullable<global::System.Int32> optionalField1 = null)
    {
        return this.SomeProc(mandatoryField, optionalField1, null);
    }
}
```

...or modify T4 template if you're using POCO entities generator.

Comment: Thanks - this technique works well. It is also possible to overload the method and provide e.g. a ComplexType to wrap the parameters up.